# Express request object overwritten during multiple AJAX calls

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

We have a 'Express' and NodeJS based web application which sends an AJAX request to get system data based on  which chart are generated in browser. The client code calls the AJAX function every 3 seconds. The server side code uses 'systeminformation' NPM to get the system CPU, MEM and other stats and sends it back to the client. Every thing works fine with timer interval of greater than 1 second.

However, on reducing the timer interval to say 500ms the server side REST API crashes with error "Can't set headers after they are sent."

On analysis we found that the server side code is taking more time to complete the call and during this time more AJAX calls are raised for the same API thus calling the same function of the server. During, these calls sometimes the response object of 2 API calls becomes same. So, when one API send the response back and another API tries to send the response, it gets this error. We verified this as follows:

Generated a random id at the entry of the API on server. So, each API calls now has an identifier. The API then calls the 'systeminformation' multiple times to get the required information. The data from 'systeminformation' is returned via callback. When the last callback of 'systeminformation' returns it send the response back to the client. We also printed the boolean 'response.headersSent' when the error occurs occurs and found that the call which end with error already has this value set to **True** before it tries to send the response back.

In the logs below 'start' log indicates the entry into the REST API function on the server. The 'cpu', 'mem' and 'fsdata' indicate the entry into the callbacks for these stats as called by 'systeminformation' module. The 'end' log indicates the point after response has been sent to client or control is inside catch. The response is sent in 'fsdata' callback. So, in ideally 'response.headersSent' should be set to false when callback is called from 'systeminformation' as it is called as a result of individual AJAX call.

For ID in bold we can see that 3 AJAX calls are running concurrently. So, now there are 3 same API calls in execution at the same time. The ID **58142** completes successfully as we can see the 'end' log for it. However, when call with ID **79793** reaches it's 'fsData' callback the response it has, has already being sent as seen by value of response.headersSent being true. This response was set to true when call for ID **58142** sent the response. So, basically the response objects for ID **58142** and **79793** somehow became same leading to this error. Same also happens for ID **52972**.

The logs are as follows:

```
54817: ----end
44024: ----start
44024: ----cpu
44024: ----mem
44024: ----fsdata
About to send response, response.headersSent: false
44024: ----end
**58142**: ----start
**79793**: ----start
58142: ----cpu
79793: ----cpu
58142: ----mem
79793: ----mem
52972: ----start
52972: ----cpu
**58142**: ----fsdata
About to send response, response.headersSent: false
**58142**: ----end
**79793**: ----fsdata
About to send response, response.headersSent: true
Inside Catch:
About to send response, response.headersSent: true
**79793**: ----end
52972: ----mem
52972: ----fsdata
About to send response, response.headersSent: true
Inside Catch:
About to send response, response.headersSent: true
52972: ----end
41519: ----start
41519: ----cpu
41519: ----mem
41519: ----fsdata
About to send response, response.headersSent: false
41519: ----end
81681: ----start
81681: ----cpu
81681: ----mem
81681: ----fsdata
About to send response, response.headersSent: false
81681: ----end
44642: ----start
44642: ----cpu
44642: ----mem
44642: ----fsdata
About to send response, response.headersSent: false
44642: ----end
94771: ----start
94771: ----cpu
94771: ----mem
94771: ----fsdata
```

Can anyone guide me on why this is happenning and is this the expected behaviour by express ?

Comment: That's a good amount of information, yet I'd say post the relevant code, with error middleware as well.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is happening because AJAX is calling the same controller everytime the api is called. Please try using Promise for this code. Each of the parameters can be chained in a promise and the result can be sent in the last.

Comment: We tried using promise also but we get the same issue of response object overriding with and without promise.